# Перевести время в текст

Tags: python

Есть значение `datetime.time(16, 0)` Нужно его перевести в строку `"16:00"`

Comment: Могли бы вы показать ваше решение?

Comment: `str(datetime.time(16, 0))`?

Comment: Переводите, раз нужно.

Comment: `datetime.time(16, 0).strftime('%H:%M')`

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вам это поможет

```
import datetime


res = str(datetime.time(16, 0))[:-3]
print(res)
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!!!